# Understand how inheritance works in java

Tags: java, oop

I'm learning oop, and I need to understand how inheritance actually works.

Let's say I have server call, with response that contain list of `Movies`, And another server call that I get the movie credits by movie id.

so my classes will look like this:

**Class Movies :**

```
public class Movies {
    private Movie[] movies;

   public Movies( Movie[] movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }
}
```

**Class Movie:**

```
public class Movie extends Movies {
    private String title;
    private int id;
    private int voteCount;

    public Movie(String title, int id, int voteCount) {
        super();//the problem
        this.title = title;
        this.id = id;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    } }
```

**Class Credits:**

```
public class Credits extends Movie {
     private int id; //movieId
       private Cast[] casts;


        public Credits(int id, Cast[] casts) {
            super();//the problem
            this.id = id;
            this.casts = casts;
        }
```

As you can see `Credits` extends `Movie` that extends from `Movies`.

The problem is for example `Credits` inherit from `Movie`, because `Credits` is part of a `Movie`, but when I extends `Movie` inside `Credits` and need to pass arguments to `super()` inside my constrcutor I don't really know what to do.

How can I get access to this arguments? why do I need to pass `voteCount` for example in my Credits` class to super constructor?

Comment: Nono, `Credits` don't extend a movie. Are credits a movie? No, they are not. What you need here is a composition between `Credits` and `Movie`.

Comment: You need to think of extends as " is a type of " So is "Movies" a type of Movie? No. Is Credits a type of Movie? No

Comment: Another thing is that "movies" is a set of movies. Thus, you should represent it in your code as a list or set of `Movie` objects.

Comment: There are some semantic erors in those classes.

Movies should basically be a List/ArrayList/Array of Movie Objects and not a Superclass.
Id recomment having a look at the Java ArrayLists(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
Credits should **not** Extend the Movie class, because it is not a Movie.
Movies of course should have Credits so the Movie Class should have one internal Credits Object.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I've better understanding of inheritance now and when should I use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using inheritance the wrong way. You have to understand what inheritance means. In programming, inheritance means **specialization**. It is not some arbitrary way to be able to access other parts of the program.

Which is to say: a subclass **is a** specialized version of its superclass.

Especially the "is a" is important. When you write:

```
public class Movie extends Movies
```

what you're really expressing is: "a Movie object **is a** (special kind of) Movies object", and

```
public class Credits extends Movie
```

"a Credits object **is a** (special kind of) Movie object".

You can already see that this doesn't make sense - a Movie is not a collection of Movie objects, and Credits are not some kind of Movie.

Theoretical explanation: [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).